# ActionListener method not called when in a conditional rendered block

Tags: jsf

I've got this code where some buttons show only under a certain condition, like this:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{mayusculasBean.jefeCerca}">
  <h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <h:commandButton value="Listar" 
        actionListener="#{gestorEmpleados.listarEmpleados}"
        immediate="true"/>
  ...`
</h:panelGroup>
```

The `rendered` attribute is working ok. The problem is that the `actionListener` method is not being called when the `commandButton` is pressed. However, if I get rid of the `rendered` attribute, the button is working properly.

I think it might be related to the different phases of the `Jsf` request, so when the `commandButton` is pressed the `rendered` attribute, I don't know why, evaluates to false, therefore avoiding the call to the `actionListener` method... but it's just a guess, I really have no idea.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you want to use the actionListener attribute instead of the action attribute?

Comment: Because I am not navigating between pages, I'm staying in the same page. Anyway that was a good tip, but I changed it to action attribute and still no method call.

Answer (score 0):

If your `mayusculasBean` is `@RequestScoped`, then, after response committed, your command button component will not be tracked by the server.

If this is your case, you need to change your `mayusculasBean` to a wider scope such as `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, simply accept this answer. :-)